# module-deps can't resolve relative require()s

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to use [module-deps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-deps) to walk the dependency graph of a Node.js file. Here's a mostly minimal testcase (see below  for the absolute bare minimum):

```
var resolve = require('resolve'),
    mdeps = require('module-deps'),
    builtins = require('builtins'),
    through2 = require('through2');

var md = mdeps({
    filter: function(id) {
        // Just ignore things built in to Node
        return !builtins(process.versions.node).includes(id);
    },
    // Use the regular Node resolution algorithm instead of whatever browser-resolve does
    resolve: resolve
});

md.pipe(through2.obj(function(dep) {
    // console.log(dep);
}));

md.end(require.resolve(__filename));
```

For some reason this is causing an error event: `Error: Cannot find module './lib/core' from '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/node_modules/resolve/index.js'`.

I cannot for the life of me nail down what's going on. I even patched `module-deps` to dump the arguments it was feeding to `resolve`, so I could reproduce the exact function call it was making. Manually giving virtually the exact same arguments to `resolve` resulted in a correct resolution.

I've Googled a lot and still can't find anything.

---

Here's an even more minimal testcase:

`test.js`:

```
require('./test2.js');
```

`test2.js`: (empty)

`test3.js`:

```
var resolve = require('resolve'),
    mdeps = require('module-deps'),
    through2 = require('through2');

var md = mdeps({
        resolve: resolve
});

md.end(require.resolve('./test.js'));
```

To test what call `module-deps` was making, I edited `node_modules/module-deps/index.js` at line 180 to add:

```
console.log('EQL', self.resolver === require('/Users/alex/Development/audittool/node_modules/resolve/index.js'));
console.log('RESOLVER', id, parent);
    self.resolver(id, parent, function onresolve (err, file, pkg, fakePath) {
        ...
```

The `self.resolver` line is for context. Running `test3.js` prints:

```
EQL true
RESOLVER /Users/alex/Development/audittool/test.js { id: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/__fake.js',
  filename: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/_fake.js',
  paths: [],
  basedir: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool',
  packageFilter: [Function],
  modules: {} }
EQL true
RESOLVER ./test2.js { id: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/test.js',
  filename: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/test.js',
  paths: [],
  package: { __dirname: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool' },
  inNodeModules: false,
  packageFilter: [Function],
  modules: {} }
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module './test2.js' from '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/test.js'
    at /Users/alex/Development/audittool/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:64:35
    at load (/Users/alex/Development/audittool/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:83:43)
    at onex (/Users/alex/Development/audittool/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:108:17)
    at /Users/alex/Development/audittool/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:12:69
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

Based on that dump, I created `resolve_test3.js` to try and recreate the `module-deps` call:

```
var resolve = require('resolve');
resolve('./test2.js', {
    id: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/test.js',
    filename: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/test.js',
    paths: [],
    package: { __dirname: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool' },
    inNodeModules: false,
    modules: {}
}, console.log);
```

But this runs successfully and prints:

```
null '/Users/alex/Development/audittool/test2.js' { __dirname: '/Users/alex/Development/audittool' }
```

AFAICT, the only difference between the two calls is that the first one had `opts.packageFilter` defined.

---

After some more detective work, I think the problem is that `module-deps` isn't properly passing `opts.basedir` to `resolve`. I inserted `if (parent.package)     parent.basedir = parent.package.__dirname;` after line 169 of `module-deps`' `index.js` (that is, the line that reads `if (opts.modules) parent.modules = opts.modules;`), and that fixed the problem.

I believe the reason that `require_test3.js` worked was because of line 35 in `node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js`:

```
var basedir = opts.basedir || path.dirname(caller());
```

Notice `caller()`. Because `resolve_test3.js` was calling `resolve` from the same directory it worked, but `module-deps` was calling it from inside `node_modules`, so it got an incorrect `basename.`

Comment: *Use the regular Node resolution algorithm instead of whatever browser-resolve does* -  seems like this is a problem with `resolve`, not with `module-deps`. *Manually giving virtually the exact same arguments to resolve resulted in a correct resolution* - please, show it for comparison. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is desirable for both cases.

Comment: @estus you're right, sorry. it was 3 AM and I was frustrated and being lazy :P

Answer (score 0):

I debugged it, and I observed that it has something to do with the way your resolve module works. If you could debug it and see, in the FSREQWRAP in fs.js module, where it tries to load the modules post writing the streams, it has list of errors :

`"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/<project_path>/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/module-deps'"`

`"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '<project_path>/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/builtins'"`

`"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/luvkarakoti/Desktop/DOS 2 UNIX/lf-crlf/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/through2'"`

( Mind that these are the very modules you have imported in the file you're triggering it and subsequently reading )

As you can see, it is trying to find for the `node_modules` inside the `module_deps`, whereas it should have searched for those inside the `<project_path>/node_modules`. Maybe you can correct the way it resolves, thereby making it point to the `<project_path>` instead of `<project_path>/node_modules/module-deps`.